# Mail delivery failed: returning message

Tags: email

We got a server with mails and several clients send us this issue can somebody help with this issue?

> ```
>  subject: Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender
> ```
>
> This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.
>
> A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
>   recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es)
>   failed:
>
> elise.dullers@spectrumstudent.be
>       SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data:
>       host ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM [2a00:1450:4013:c00::1b]:
>       550-5.7.1 [2a01:7c8:aaaa:3e7::1] Our system has detected that this message does
>       550-5.7.1 not meet IPv6 sending guidelines regarding PTR records and
>       550-5.7.1 authentication. Please review
>       550-5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=IPv6AuthError for more information
>       550 5.7.1 . z13si75087edl.403 - gsmtp
>
> ------ This is a copy of the message, including all the headers. ------
>
> Return-path:  Received: from
>   109.131-67-87.adsl-dyn.isp.belgacom.be ([87.67.131.109] helo=[192.168.1.55]) by server.ireto.be with esmtpa (Exim 4.83)
>   (envelope-from ) id 1egDid-0005am-Ee for
>   elise.dullers@spectrumstudent.be; Mon, 29 Jan 2018 18:59:48 +0100
>   SavedFromEmail: info@beringsetaxi.be Date: Mon, 29 Jan 2018 18:59:44
>   +0100 Subject: Re: Kostprijs taxi In-Reply-To: 
>   Importance: normal From: info  To: Elise Dullers
>    MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type:
>   multipart/alternative;
>   boundary="--_com.samsung.android.email_2340489603438420"
>
> ----_com.samsung.android.email_2340489603438420 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

Comment: Try to understand when this problem started. From wich day and what you have modify in your system. 
The error says a ipv6 problem

Comment: Without code to discuss, this is completely off-topic for SO. Add the code that has the problem, or post somewhere else like ServerFault.